# How to change drop down button in combobox control?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

How to change dropdown button in a `ComboBox` control (C#, Windows Forms)? I have a custom button, and I want to use it in the `ComboBox` instead of the default dropdown button.

Comment: You need [`VisualStyleRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx)

Comment: do you want to extend the combobox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Hans Passant solution is the way...

From here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/5d65f987-834c-465f-a944-622831d4cfb0

> You can create a UserControl, drag a
>   ComboBox and a Button onto it, make
>   the Button right over the ComboBox's
>   arrow button to make the arrow button
>   invisible, handle the Button's Paint
>   event to draw an arrow on it, this can
>   be done by calling
>   ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton()
>   method (Notice: this method has a
>   limit, it needs the visual style being
>   enabled on the OS) or by drawing an
>   icon on it, or just drawing a small
>   triangle on it.
>        Then handle the Click event of the button to show the ComboBox's
>   DropDown, this can be done by
>   something like this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```